# Applying local timezone in Django templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, timezone

I use Django 3.1.7 and postgreSQL for the database.

So here is the problem, after saving a date in my database I try to display it in a template with the timezone of the visitor and it's still displaying me the date UTC.

I have these values in my settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

my model:

```py
class Log(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    log = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(to=Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

my context processor getting me the objects:

```py
def logs_processor(request):
    if request.user.has_perm('loging.can_see_logs'):
        try:
            logs = Log.objects.filter(company=request.user.company).order_by('-date')[:50]
        except TypeError:
            logs = None
        return {'side_logs': logs}
    else:
        return {'side_logs': []}
```

And my template:

```
{% load tz %}
{% for log in side_logs %}
   {{ log.date|localtime }}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried without the |localtime but no luck.

When I specify by hand the TZ like `log.date|timezone:"Europe/Paris"` That works well.

As well I precise that I have `pytz` installed.

Here what my dates look like in the database (it seams they are not naive and placed on UTC as planed):
`2021-03-10 04:10:11.849048 +00:00`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [`localtime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#localtime) filter says that it "enables or disables conversion of aware datetime objects to the current time zone". The *current time zone* is [defined](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) as the one that was explicitly set by calling `activate()` or, failing that, is the value of the `TIME_ZONE` setting.

You're not calling `activate()`, and the value of the `TIME_ZONE` setting is `UTC`, so that's why you're seeing the values in `UTC`.

If your goal is to use the "timezone of the visitor" you're going to have to do more work, because there's no way for the server to automatically know what time zone the user wants to use. The documentation [discusses this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone), and gives some examples of how you might do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kevin, I'm a bit lost, if I understand well: There is no way to know dynamicaly with the browser, which timezone the user is right now so we can not have an automatic timezone display. But we can save in the user his "prefered" timezone and activate the display on this timezone, knowing that if the user change TimeZone he will have to update it on his profile. Am I right?

Comment: @Tartempion34: Right, that's what's shown in the documentation example, but ultimately it's up to you. Standard practice is that you always want to use the user's preferred time zone, even if, say, they happen to be traveling and using a computer in a different time zone. But if you instead want to try and figure out the time zone of the browser dynamically (using Javascript in the client, say, or some server-side tool based on IP address), then you can do that. But Django can't do that for you, it's always your responsibility to say what the "local" time zone is using `activate()`.

Comment: Worked like a charm with the middleware and the user TZ. Thanks a lot